# Snakemake stuck at activating conda environment

Tags: anaconda, conda, snakemake

I am using Snakemake to run a QIIME2 pipeline on an HPC but am running an issue where during one of my rules Snakemake is stuck indefinitely when activating the conda environment (won't activate after 3 days), but this same environment is activated just fine for the other rules (takes <1hr).

Here is the job log where it is stuck:

```
The flag 'directory' used in rule all is only valid for outputs, not inputs.
The flag 'directory' used in rule rename_files_import is only valid for outputs, not inputs.
Building DAG of jobs...
Your conda installation is not configured to use strict channel priorities. This is however crucial for having robust and correct environments (for details, see https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html). Please consider to configure strict priorities by executing 'conda config --set channel_priority strict'.
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 16
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Provided resources: mem_mb=1000, mem_mib=954, disk_mb=1000, disk_mib=954
Select jobs to execute...

[Wed Feb  7 16:38:16 2024]
rule deblur:
    input: <hidden>
    output: <hidden>
    log: <hidden>
    jobid: 0
    reason: Missing output files: <hidden>
    resources: mem_mb=1000, mem_mib=954, disk_mb=1000, disk_mib=954, tmpdir=/tmp

Activating conda environment: .snakemake/conda/<hidden>
```

Here is an example job log that runs successfully activating that same environment:

```
The flag 'directory' used in rule all is only valid for outputs, not inputs.
The flag 'directory' used in rule rename_files_import is only valid for outputs, not inputs.
Building DAG of jobs...
Your conda installation is not configured to use strict channel priorities. This is however crucial for having robust and correct environments (for details, see https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html). Please consider to configure strict priorities by executing 'conda config --set channel_priority strict'.
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 10
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Provided resources: mem_mb=1000, mem_mib=954, disk_mb=1000, disk_mib=954
Select jobs to execute...

[Tue Feb  6 22:30:34 2024]
rule quality_filter:
    input: <hidden>
    output: <hidden>
    log: <hidden>
    jobid: 0
    reason: Missing output files: <hidden>
    resources: mem_mb=1000, mem_mib=954, disk_mb=1000, disk_mib=954, tmpdir=/tmp

Activating conda environment: .snakemake/conda/<hidden>
Saved SampleData[JoinedSequencesWithQuality] to: <hidden>
Saved QualityFilterStats to: <hidden>
Saved Visualization to: <hidden>
[Tue Feb  6 22:54:00 2024]
Finished job 0.
1 of 1 steps (100%) done
```

Here is a snippet of my Snakefile -- one of the rules where the environment is activated successfully and the code runs:

```
rule demux_summarize:
    input: 
        q2_import = OUTPUT + PROJ + "-PE-demux.qza",
        q2_primerRM = OUTPUT + PROJ + "-PE-demux-noprimer.qza",
        q2_merged = OUTPUT + PROJ + "-PE-demux-noprimer-merged.qza",
        q2_qualfilter = OUTPUT + PROJ + "-PE-demux-noprimer-merged-filtered.qza"
    output:
        raw = VISUALIZATION + PROJ + "-PE-demux.qzv",
        primer = VISUALIZATION + PROJ + "-PE-demux-noprimer.qzv",
        merged = VISUALIZATION + PROJ + "-PE-demux-noprimer-merged.qzv",
        filtered = VISUALIZATION + PROJ + "-PE-demux-noprimer-merged-filtered.qzv"
    conda:
        "envs/qiime2-amplicon-2023.9-py38-linux-conda.yml"
    shell:
        """
        qiime demux summarize --i-data {input.q2_import} --o-visualization {output.raw}
        qiime demux summarize --i-data {input.q2_primerRM} --o-visualization {output.primer}
        qiime demux summarize --i-data {input.q2_merged} --o-visualization {output.merged}
        qiime demux summarize --i-data {input.q2_qualfilter} --o-visualization {output.filtered}
        """
```

And here is the rule where Snakemake is stuck:

```
rule deblur:
  input:
    q2_qualfilter = OUTPUT + PROJ + "-PE-demux-noprimer-merged-filtered.qza",
    ref_database_fasta = REFFASTA, 
    
  output:
    table = OUTPUT + PROJ + "-table.qza",
    rep = OUTPUT + PROJ + "-rep-seqs.qza",
    stats = OUTPUT + PROJ + "-deblur-stats.qza",
    deblur_stats = VISUALIZATION + PROJ + "-deblur-stats.qzv"
  log:
    OUTPUT + "qiime2/logs/" + PROJ + "-deblur.log"
  conda:
    "envs/qiime2-amplicon-2023.9-py38-linux-conda.yml"
  shell:
    """
    qiime deblur denoise-other \
        --i-demultiplexed-seqs {input.q2_qualfilter} \
        --i-reference-seqs {input.ref_database_fasta} \
        --p-trim-length {config[p_trim_length]} \
        --p-no-hashed-feature-ids \
        --o-representative-sequences {output.rep} \
        --o-table {output.table} \
        --p-sample-stats \
        --p-jobs-to-start 16 \
        --o-stats {output.stats} \
        --p-min-reads=1
        
    qiime demux summarize --i-data {output.stats} --o-visualization {output.deblur_stats}
    """
```

I am submitting snakemake jobs with the following code:

```
snakemake   \
        -s ../Snakefile --jobs 100  --use-conda --conda-frontend conda --cluster \
        "sbatch -p {cluster.partition} --job-name={rule} --mem={cluster.mem} --time={cluster.time} --ntasks={cluster.ntasks} --nodes={cluster.nodes}  --output=slurm-logs/%x.%j.log --verbose" \
        --cluster-config ../cluster.yaml --latency-wait 120
```

I need to run --conda-frontend conda because mamba is not installed on the anaconda module on my cluster environment. I am using anaconda ver 2022.10 and snakemake ver 7.22.0+py3.11.0 which are installed as software modules on the cluster. I have asked them to update anaconda as that might help conda run faster? Even so, I don't understand why the activation would work on all rules but the one. I would greatly appreciate any insight!

Comment: Have you checked if the job is running? Check if the expected output files/logs are being produced. Snakemake prints "activating conda env", and then begins the shell command(s), so it may be that the job is running but is not producing any stderr/stdout.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response! The job is running -- the output log that I included is for the job that is running, I have the submit script running as well as the deblur job, I can see them both running in my queue

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your OP properly, but I guess would you expect this job to take 3 days? I've run into this before where the log only says "activating conda env" for hours and I thought nothing was being done, but the job was actually running as I could see the output file of that job growing in size.

Comment: Yes, I also question the inference that it is having trouble activating. Add something like `echo "[INFO] Script started."` to the top of the `script:` code. If that get's emitted, then it's not a Conda problem.

Comment: Also, you can simply install [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge) (comes with Mamba) in your user directory. I would not rely on a centralized Conda like this.

Comment: Oh! Thank you both so much! Yes I confirmed that it is running and installed miniforge and now it is also working a lot faster overall. Much appreciated -- am very new to snakemake!